# Telegram Bot set reminder

Tags: python, pycharm, telegram, python-telegram-bot, reminders

Hello guys i am currently developing a telegram bot which can set reminders. However, i am facing a lot of errors while doing this task.
The coding that i used:

```
update.message.reply_text("What should i remind you about?")
    remind = update.message.text
       
    update.message.reply_text("Enter Hours")
    alarmHour = int(update.message.text)
    update.message.reply_text("Enter Minutes")
    alarmMin = int(update.message.text)
    update.message.reply_text("am / pm: ")
    AP = str(update.message.text)

    if AP == "pm":
        alarmHour += 12
    
    while True:
        if alarmHour == datetime.datetime.now().hour and alarmMin == datetime.datetime.now().minute:
            update.message.reply_text(remind)
            break
```

The errors i faced:
caused error invalid literal for int() with base 10: '/reminder'

I also realised that we couldnt ask for more than one input from users in the same command. Do any of you guys know how to solve this problem?

Comment: What do you expect `alarmMin = int(update.message.text)` and `AP = int(update.message.text)` to do?

Comment: alarmMin is the minutes entered by users.for example,alarmHour:10 and alarmMin =15. so the time will be 10:15. AP is what users choose between AM and PM

Comment: And what do you think will happen when you try to do `int("pm")` or `int("/reminder")`?

Comment: The bot only responds if it accepts "am" or "pm" in the AP part. i will add the try catch method later to let the users know about the invalid input if they send anything other than "am" or "pm"

Comment: That code doesn't do what you think it does. Take a look at [an example](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.0a4/examples.conversationbot.html) for handling sequential messages.

Answer (score 0):

use [ConversationHandler](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.conversationhandler.html) instead of update message
because update message method is not wait for user message

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34481176)